# Knockout JS changing my viewmodel creation to use mapping pulgin

Tags: javascript, mapping, knockout.js

I am relatively new to `Knockout.js` and have a question regarding the creating of the view model.

What I am currently doing is:

```
viewModel = {

                Menu: ko.observableArray(ko.utils.parseJson(data)),

                editMenu: function (menu) {
                    ko.applyBindings(menu, document.getElementById("MenuCategories"));
                    $("#MenuCategories").bPopup();
                }
```

There is more than one function, but trying to keep it short.

What I want to do is use the mapping plugin because my json data that I am using contains arrays of objects with each object containing an array and each object in that array also contains an array. What the JSON looks like:

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Test 5",
    "Description": "Testing menu",
    "BeveragesMenu": false,
    "Active": true,
    "Categories": [
      {
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "Test 1",
        "Active": true,
        "MenuItems": [
        {
          "Id": 1,
          "Name": "Food",
          "Description": "2 Eggs and Bread",
          "Price": 50,
          "DateBased": false,
          "PriceOnRequest": false,
          "DateFrom": null,
          "DateTo": null,
          "Active": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Id": 2,
      "Name": "Test 2",
      "Active": true,
      "MenuItems": [
        ]
     },
     {
       "Id": 1004,
       "Name": "test",
       "Active": true,
       "MenuItems": [
        ]
     },
     {
       "Id": 1005,
       "Name": "Test 4",
       "Active": true,
       "MenuItems": [
         ]
     }
   ]
 },
 {
   "Id": 92,
   "Name": "Test 4",
   "Description": "",
   "BeveragesMenu": false,
   "Active": false,
   "Categories": [
   {
     "Id": 1006,
     "Name": "Test 1",
     "Active": true,
     "MenuItems": [
     {
       "Name": "Test",
       "Description": "",
       "Price": "",
       "DateBased": false,
       "PriceOnRequest": false
      }
    ]
  }
]
},
{
"Id": 93,
"Name": "Test 6",
"Description": "",
"BeveragesMenu": false,
"Active": false,
"Categories": [

]
},
{
"Id": 94,
"Name": "Test 9",
"Description": "",
"BeveragesMenu": false,
"Active": false,
"Categories": [

]
},
{
  "Id": 95,
  "Name": "Test 20]",
  "Description": "",
  "BeveragesMenu": false,
  "Active": false,
  "Categories": [
  {
    "Id": 4,
    "Name": "Test 6666",
    "Active": true,
    "MenuItems": [

    ]
  }
]
},
{
  "Id": 96,
  "Name": "Test 444",
  "Description": "",
  "BeveragesMenu": false,
  "Active": false,
  "Categories": [
  {
    "Id": 3,
    "Name": "Test 555",
    "Active": true,
    "MenuItems": [

    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": 5,
    "Name": "Test 6666",
    "Active": true,
    "MenuItems": [

    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": 1003,
    "Name": "test 777",
    "Active": true,
    "MenuItems": [

    ]
  }
]
}
]
```

Sorry for the long JSON code paste.

So now I am running into problems when updating certain parts of the objects within arrays withing objects etc.

So I taught that the mapping plugin might solve my problem as it creates all arrays as observable and I am assuming that is my problem.

So I tried:

```
viewModel = {
                Menu: ko.mapping.fromJSON(ko.utils.parseJson(data)),
                //Menu: ko.observableArray(ko.utils.parseJson(data)),

                editMenu: function (menu) {
                    ko.applyBindings(menu, document.getElementById("MenuCategories"));
                    $("#MenuCategories").bPopup();
                },
```

But then none of my binding are working and I can't seem to find the cause, any advice or tips on this matter would be appreciated.

Here is a Fiddle of all the things I have tried. http://jsfiddle.net/armandvdwalt/pjJc2/3/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pjJc2/7/), I switched the order of the resources. You were referencing the mapping plugin before knockout which was generating a script error about not recognizing "ko." Also, you don't need to use ko.utils.parseJson when using fromJSON, as fromJSON expects JSON as an argument.